# Linksys Router Remote access to LAN network, Static Routes

Tags: router, remote-access, static-routes

I am trying to set up remote access to a controller on my LAN-side network from off-site.  I can hit the remote access page of the router, but I am unable to hit any of my equipment on the LAN side below the router.

Linksys Broadband Firewall Router   BEFSX41

Firewall options are all shut off
put my piece of equipment in the DMZ
set up port forwarding on the 3 ports my equipment talks on
set up UPnP forwarding to the ip address of my equipment on the LAN side.

What setting am I missing here?  I have another employee at a remote location testing access, and he can get all the way to the remote management portal on the router, so I know we are at least talking that far.  How can I configure a static route from the static IP address my ISP has provided me to the static IP address of my piece of equipment with this router?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the device you're trying to connect to in the 'DMZ' of a Linksys router (or firewall with the firewall features turned off), any connections to the public IP of the router should be forwarded on to the 'DMZ' IP.

You should disable remote administration in the router config so the router stops listening on port 80, and will then forward the request on to your internal device.